# System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format..

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

This error is occuring when running the msi created by a Visual Studio 2010 x64 project w/ .Net Framework 4.0.  The 'Project Output' file is also x64.

I resolved this issue by removing the 'Custom Action' steps from the install, successfully running the install, then manually running the 64-bit version of InstallUtil.

I have seen posts circa VS 2005 documenting this and thus was able to figure out how to resolve my issue.

My question is:  Is there a way to fix this via the GUI interface or do I have to modify the MSI with Orca after it has been created???